# How to fix Node-express app serving server files through url?

Tags: node.js, express

I am facing a problem with my application in live server. My node.js application is serving backend javascript code through url. how to stop serving backend javascript codes from my application. but when I build it on my local machine, it wasn't serving server files.

application root : https://node.shophabb.com.

files serveing problem example : https://node.shophabb.com/index.js

I use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))` to serve static files

I am using a namecheap hosting. I use there (Setup Node.js App) feature.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put index.js in public folder ?

move index.js to root folder and make sure package.json have

```
"main": "index.js"
```